# Advice for low power consumption motherboard for pfSense firewall with almost 3 lan (Alix 2d13, Apu2c4 or others)

Tags: motherboard, firewall, pfsense

I'm looking for a motherboard for a pfSense-based firewall with low power consumption (about 10 watts) and 3 LAN ports. Looking for a solution I found these motherboards: Alix 2d13 and Apu2c4 but I'm more inclined to apu2c4 because it should have gigabit LAN ports. What's the best for you?

If you know other motherboards that meet my requirements please propose them as well.